# No consigo obtener el valor del label que quiero cambiar

Tags: javascript

Estoy pasando la información de un `textarea` con formato `JSON` a un `formulario`.

Cualquier campo que yo cambie dentro del `JSON`, repercute en el propio `formulario` exceptuando los `label`, que no consigo que cambien. Si cambian su `value`, es a `undefined` o a `[obj Obj]`

Lo que trato de hacer es que el cambio que haga sea bidireccional, es decir:

- Si cambio el label (contenteditable='true') en el formulario, se cambia en el textarea con formato JSON (Esto funciona).
- Si cambio el label en el textarea JSON, se debería cambiar también su valor en el formulario (Esto no funciona).

Aquí dejo el ejemplo (siento que el mínimo verificable sea tan largo, pero lo tengo todo metido dentro de una class en js para trabajar el código en otras plataformas):

```js
class formLOGOSTariff{

   constructor(id, idtxt, params){
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;
      var temForm    = document.querySelector("#temp-form").innerHTML;
      this.id = id;
      this.idtxt = idtxt;
      let foorm = document.createElement('div');
         foorm.innerHTML = temForm;
         document.getElementById(id).appendChild(foorm);

      this.contentForm = foorm.querySelector(".content-form");


      foorm.querySelector(".btn-event-addFrm").addEventListener("click",()=>{
         this.addFrm();
      });
      foorm.querySelector(".btn-event-sndFrm").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         this.sndFrm();
      });
      foorm.querySelector(".btn-event-delFrm").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         this.delFrm();
      });

      let card = this.addFrm();

      document.body.querySelector('.btn-event-sndTo').addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         this.sndTo();
      });

      var txtare = document.getElementById(this.idtxt);

      txtare.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
         if (!txtare.value){}
            else{
         this.sndTo();
         }
      });

      for (let i in params){
         var hdninpt = document.createElement('input');
         hdninpt.type = 'hidden';
         hdninpt.name = i;
         hdninpt.value = params[i];

         foorm.querySelector('form').appendChild(hdninpt);
      };
   }

   addPower(el)   {
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

      let power = document.createElement("div");
      power.innerHTML = temPower;
      el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);

      power.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(item=>{
            item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
               this.sndFrm();
            });
         });

      power.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach(item=>{
         item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            this.sndFrm();
         });
      });

      power.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach(item=>{
         item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            this.sndFrm();
         });
      });


      return power;

   }

   addEnergy(el)   {
      var temEnergy  =  document.querySelector('#temp-energy').innerHTML;

      let energy = document.createElement('div');
         energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;
            el.querySelector('.container-energy').appendChild(energy);

      energy.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(item=>{
            item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
               this.sndFrm();
            });
         });

      energy.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach(item=>{
         item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            this.sndFrm();
         });
      });

      energy.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach(item=>{
         item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            this.sndFrm();
         });
      });
               return energy;
   }

   addFrm() {
      var tmp = document.querySelector('#temp-card').innerHTML;
      var cont = this.contentForm;
      let frm  = document.createElement('div');
     
         frm.innerHTML = tmp;
         cont.appendChild(frm);

         frm.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(item=>{
            item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
               this.sndFrm();
            });
         });

         frm.querySelectorAll(".name_tarif").forEach(item=>{
            item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
               this.sndFrm();
            });
         });
         frm.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-addPower").forEach(item=>{
           item.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
               this.addPower(frm);
            }); 
         })
         frm.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-addEnergy").forEach(item=>{
           item.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
               this.addEnergy(frm);
            }); 
         })

         this.addPower(frm);
         this.addEnergy(frm);
      return frm;
   }

   sndFrm()   {
      var jotason = [];

      this.contentForm.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

            let obj = {
               title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
            };

            let lbl = {};
            form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = lbl[index]||{};
               ob.type=inpt.innerHTML;
               lbl[index]=ob;
            });

            let power = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.type=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.value=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            let energy = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.type=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.value=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            obj.lbl = lbl;
            obj.power = power;
            obj.energy = energy;
            jotason.push(obj);

      })
      var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);

      document.getElementById(this.idtxt).value=jsoned;
   }

   sndTo(){
      this.contentForm.innerHTML='';
      let pJsn = document.getElementById(this.idtxt).value;
      var dat  = JSON.parse(pJsn);
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{

            let formDv = this.addFrm();

            formDv.querySelector(".container-power").innerHTML='';

               for(let n1 in form.power){
                  (pow=>{
                     let power = this.addPower(formDv);
                     power.querySelector(".lbl-tmp-crd").innerHTML=form.lbl[1];
                     console.log(form.lbl[1]);
                     power.querySelector("[name=t_power]").value=pow.type;
                     power.querySelector("[name=v_power]").value=pow.value;
                  })(form.power[n1])
               }

            formDv.querySelector(".container-energy").innerHTML='';

               for(let n2 in form.energy){
                  (eng=>{
                     let energy = this.addEnergy(formDv);
                     energy.querySelector(".lbl-tmp-crd").innerHTML=form.lbl[2].value;
                     console.log(form.lbl[2]);
                     energy.querySelector("[name=t_energy]").value=eng.type;
                     energy.querySelector("[name=v_energy]").value=eng.value;
                  })(form.energy[n2])
               }

            formDv.querySelector(".name_tarif").value=form.title;
            formDv.querySelector(".lbl-tmp-crd").innerHTML=form.lbl[0].value;
            console.log(form.lbl[0]);
           
         })(dat[n]);
      }
   }

   delFrm(){
      var nm = this.contentForm.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD").length -1;
      var cont = this.contentForm.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD")[nm];
      if (nm > 0){
         if(confirm('¿Quieres borrarlo')){
            cont.remove();
         } else {}
      } else {}
   }
}

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
   var nomVre1 = new formLOGOSTariff("test-1", "test-atex-1", {key:100});
   var nomVre2 = new formLOGOSTariff("test-2", "test-atex-2", {key:202});
   var nomVre3 = new formLOGOSTariff("test-3", "test-atex-3", {key:323});
   var nomVre4 = new formLOGOSTariff("test-4", "test-atex-4", {key:575});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template id="temp-card">
 
    <div class="templatecARD" data-group="0" >

        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true'>Tarifa</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif"/>
        
        <div>

            <div class="container-power"></div>
            <button class="btn-event-addPower" type="button">+</button>

        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="container-energy" ></div>
            <button class="btn-event-addEnergy" type="button">+</button>

        </div>

    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-power">
    <div class="box-power" >
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true'>PRECIOS POR POTENCIA</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_power" style="width:40px"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_power"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-energy">
    <div class="box-energy" >
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true'>PRECIOS POR ENERGÍA</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_energy" style="width:40px"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_energy"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="">
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->


    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<template id="temp-form">
    <form method="post">

        <div class="content-form">

        </div>
            
        <div>
            <button class="btn-event-sndFrm" type="button">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
            <button class="btn-event-addFrm" type="button"  >+</button>
            <button class="btn-event-delFrm" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->






<div class="dv-content">
    <div id="test-1"></div>
    <textarea id="test-atex-1" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>

<div class="dv-content">
    <div id="test-2"></div>
    <textarea id="test-atex-2" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>

<div class="dv-content">
    <div id="test-3"></div>
    <textarea id="test-atex-3" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>

<div class="dv-content">
    <div id="test-4"></div>
    <textarea id="test-atex-4" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

En el propio ejemplo he puesto un console.log donde se ven los valores obtenidos como objetos.